# Model.save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit' django error

Tags: python, django, django-forms

im trying implement the register form and i geting this erorr:
**Model.save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'**

And I wrote the save method, but I still get an error

forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = CustomUser
    fields = ['email', 'password', 'password2']


    def save(self, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super(RegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

views.py

```
class UserRegisterView(View):
User = get_user_model()
form_class = forms.RegisterForm
template_name = 'account/register.html'

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.user.is_authenticated == True:
        return redirect('home:home')
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get(self, request):

    form = self.form_class()
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        user_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        new_user = CustomUser(email=user_email)
        new_user.set_password(user_password)
        new_user.is_active = False
        new_user.save(commit=False)
        activateemail(request, new_user, user_email)


        return redirect('account:user_login')

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Comment: does the save method have proper indentation

Comment: @UchihaAJ Yes, but there was a mistake here I edited it

Comment: can you also post the exact error message. The save method is called in multiple places.

Comment: this is error i got it " Model.save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit' "

Answer (score 1):

Django `Model.save` doesn't have commit param, see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects) detail. So remove `commit=False` from `new_user.save(commit=False)`. if you look code, `new_user` is instance of model `new_user = CustomUser(email=user_email)`, not form instance.

May be you are confused with `Form.save` method.